# A question on vue-router when refreshing the page

Tags: vue.js, router

I am developing a website over vue and flask

I got pages named 'index' and 'edit'

I route index to edit with the following codes

```
 edit(filename) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: `/edit/${filename}`,
      });
```

But I found that when I refresh my web page in edit/my_shedule with the button the Edge brought, my web page will be rerouted to index. What's wrong with my code?

Thank you for your advices.

I expect to stay in edit/my_shedule when I refresh my web page.

my router file is listed import VueRouter from 'vue-router' import

```
LoginPage from '../components/login'  
import IndexPage from '../components/index'  
import TablePage from '../components/EditableTable'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/login', 
        name: 'LoginPage', 
        component: LoginPage 
    },
    {
        path: '/index', 
        name: 'IndexPage', 
        component: IndexPage 
    },
    {
        path: '/edit/newTable',
        name: 'TablePage',
        component: TablePage 
    },
    {
        path: '/edit/:filename',
        component: TablePage,
    }, ]


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history', 
    base: process.env.BASE_URL, 
    routes  })


export default router
```

Comment: could you share with us route file?

Comment: I d just uploaded^-^ Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that ```Vue.use(VueRouter)``` is not present in your ```router.js```?

Comment: It seems no error with your router file, maybe other files,